# What is the final stand in Modern Warfare 3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've been wondering this for a long time. While a multiplayer map is loading in Modern Warfare 3, the intel shows that if I survive the final stand I can stand up again.

What does that mean and what is the final stand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final Stand is a Death Streak perk. Instead of being killed by normal gun fire, you are knocked to the ground and can crawl around. If you survive long enough, you can stand back up.

Final Stand happens once per life. If you get "knocked down" again, you die.

Final Stand does not activate if you die from a headshot, explosion or fall damage.

Comment: you can use any weapon when you are in final stand

Comment: I think that I have seen it one time but i haven't thought about that being the final stand.

Comment: Haven't used this death streak in a while, but I think you might be able to use it more than once in a life. Maybe if you use it, get specialist, and go down again. I think that's happened to me.